# Can't boot into Windows7 or Ubuntu 12.04 after running boot-repair

Tags: 12.04, grub2, dual-boot, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on EFI system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152144/installing-ubuntu-12-04-on-efi-system)

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my preinstalled windows 7 Sony vaio E series laptop following instructions here: http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/

Everything went well and I am able to boot into Windows after completing installation of Ubuntu. Now following instructions on web I tried to add Ubuntu to my BIOS using Easy BCD (but forget to add windows 7 entry). As a result, I loose Windows 7 OS and can't boot into either OS then I successfully repaired Windows 7 using recovery CD.

Now my problem is that I can't reinstall Ubuntu 12.04 using Live CD it halts every time before disk partition step giving error.

> ubi-partman crashed.
>   ubi-partman failed with exit code 141. further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing? If you do not, your installation may fail entirely or may be broken.

and, any choice to continue will result in the same error.

After that following some solutions I ran boot-repair commands in terminal (from Live Ubuntu mode) and got the following output. :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1206434/

Now, after restart I can't boot into either Windows or Ubuntu.

Even any attempt to run Windows repair is failed and I got the message :

> 'No operating System found'

I don't know what went wrong after running boot-repair command.

Please help in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your Windows was installed in `UEFI mode`. EasyBCD broke it because it is not UEFI compatible. `Do NOT use EasyBCD` on this computer.
2. Windows Recovery `deleted Ubuntu`.
3. Boot a Ubuntu liveCD, choose `Try Ubuntu`, via [Gparted](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) place a `boot` flag on `sda3`. Reboot the PC, you should access Windows.
4. Then you can `install Ubuntu in UEFI mode`, by following the `1st paragraph` of this [UEFI Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI).